# Retrieving table contents from NSE website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to retrieve all table contents from [NSE official website](https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm?cat=G), but only getting headings of the table.

[This is the table that I'm trying to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EugFM.png)

[These are the elements I'm trying to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz8d6.png)

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm?cat=G'
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find('table',id="topGainers")
for i in tables: 
    print(i.text)
```

[This is the result I'm getting. This only contains the columns of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4fa.png)

I tried to get the whole table but only manage to retrieve the columns name.

Answer (score 2):

The data is loaded dynamically by JS, however, you can get it from a JSON endpoint.

Here's how:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/gainers/niftyGainers1.json"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

data = pd.json_normalize(requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["data"])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
       symbol  ...                               lastCorpAnnouncement
0     HCLTECH  ...                 Interim Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share
1    HDFCLIFE  ...                       Dividend - Rs 1.70 Per Share
2        INFY  ...              Interim Dividend - Rs 16.50 Per Share
3   NESTLEIND  ...                Interim Dividend - Rs 120 Per Share
4         UPL  ...                         Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share
5   COALINDIA  ...               Interim Dividend - Rs 5.25 Per Share
6  ULTRACEMCO  ...  Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 38 Per Share
7  TATACONSUM  ...  Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs  6.05 Per...
8        ONGC  ...                  Interim Dividend - Rs 4 Per Share
9    HINDALCO  ...   Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 4 Per Share

[10 rows x 12 columns]
```

You can *pretty print* the data with `tabulate`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/gainers/niftyGainers1.json"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

data = pd.json_normalize(requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["data"])
print(tabulate(data, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
data.to_csv("nifty_gainers.csv", index=False) # Saves the table to a .csv file
```

Output:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| symbol     | series   | openPrice   | highPrice   | lowPrice   | ltp       | previousPrice   |   netPrice | tradedQuantity   | turnoverInLakhs   | lastCorpAnnouncementDate   | lastCorpAnnouncement                                 |
|------------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
| HCLTECH    | EQ       | 1,088.20    | 1,117.10    | 1,084.05   | 1,114.75  | 1,072.40        |       3.95 | 33,66,312        | 37,128.40         | 19-Jan-2023                | Interim Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share                   |
| HDFCLIFE   | EQ       | 464.05      | 477.30      | 464.00     | 472.30    | 461.40          |       2.36 | 59,41,900        | 28,035.67         | 31-May-2022                | Dividend - Rs 1.70 Per Share                         |
| INFY       | EQ       | 1,430.00    | 1,442.90    | 1,425.60   | 1,436.55  | 1,404.10        |       2.31 | 34,35,066        | 49,269.15         | 27-Oct-2022                | Interim Dividend - Rs 16.50 Per Share                |
| NESTLEIND  | EQ       | 18,498.90   | 18,865.00   | 18,474.95  | 18,865.00 | 18,450.65       |       2.25 | 85,985           | 16,117.97         | 31-Oct-2022                | Interim Dividend - Rs 120 Per Share                  |
| UPL        | EQ       | 705.50      | 711.85      | 696.80     | 711.65    | 696.40          |       2.19 | 6,48,474         | 4,568.63          | 27-Jul-2022                | Dividend - Rs 10 Per Share                           |
| COALINDIA  | EQ       | 222.00      | 225.75      | 221.35     | 225.55    | 220.85          |       2.13 | 56,92,911        | 12,756.11         | 08-Feb-2023                | Interim Dividend - Rs 5.25 Per Share                 |
| ULTRACEMCO | EQ       | 7,159.15    | 7,242.65    | 7,159.15   | 7,242.45  | 7,104.60        |       1.94 | 1,84,289         | 13,302.46         | 02-Aug-2022                | Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 38 Per Share    |
| TATACONSUM | EQ       | 698.00      | 708.65      | 694.40     | 707.00    | 694.00          |       1.87 | 12,24,220        | 8,610.80          | 09-Jun-2022                | Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs  6.05 Per Share |
| HINDALCO   | EQ       | 389.25      | 392.75      | 386.55     | 391.20    | 384.95          |       1.62 | 42,98,012        | 16,754.08         | 11-Aug-2022                | Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Rs 4 Per Share     |
| BHARTIARTL | EQ       | 750.00      | 757.65      | 739.15     | 757.00    | 745.95          |       1.48 | 61,46,833        | 45,776.69         | 01-Aug-2022                | Dividend - Rs 3 Per Share                            |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way I can save this data into csv format?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh yes it's possible. See the update answer.